# How to convert SQL to Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Is there a way to convert the `MATCH` and `AGAINST` parts to [Arel](https://github.com/nkallen/arel)?

I could not find anything about it in the Arel source code.

I'm using Rails 3.

```
SELECT gigs.time, gigs.channel_id, gigs.song_id, gigs.id, 
  MATCH (songs.title) AGAINST (?) AS song_score,
  MATCH (artists.name) AGAINST (?) AS artist_score
  FROM songs
  INNER JOIN artists ON artists.id = songs.artist_id
  INNER JOIN gigs ON gigs.song_id = songs.id
  WHERE MATCH (artists.name) AGAINST (?) OR
  MATCH (songs.title) AGAINST (?)
  HAVING (artist_score + song_score) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Arel `MATCH AGAINST` implementation. My guess is because it is not pure SQL, but specific to MySQL.